# Why does this compile

Tags: c#

I have trouble understanding what the following code *means* (and partly, why it even compiles).

We have the following snippet:

```
if (true) return;
{
    ... // Unreachable code detected
}
```

Why does this even compile?

**Am I correct in thinking that the compiler *assumes an `else` in this construct*?** If not, how does it work?

I think it must be logically equivalent to

```
if (true) 
    return;
else
{
    ...; // Unreachable code detected.
}
```

I'm in doubt, because the compiler doesn't seem to interpret the following as an if-else

```
if (condition) 
{
    ...
}
{
    ...
}
```

It does compile, but the second block gets executed no matter what.

Is this behavior explicitly stated in the C# specs?

Comment: Your last example is NOT a compile error. Nor are your first two examples equivalent.

Comment: If you cannot even bother to test the code you claim will cause compiler errors do not ask the question.

Comment: edited the question to be (more) constructive and voted to reopen.

Comment: I think the OP needs to edit the question, because I am not sure you have guessed correctly what he was asking, in total; I think he was *also* asking why "unreachable code" will compile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't assume an `else` here, it's just that any code of the form:

```
if(condition)
{
    code A

    return;
}

code B
```

is logically equivalent to:

```
if(condition)
{
    code A

    return;
}
else
{
    code B
}
```

Because `code B` will only ever be reached if `condition` evaluates to false.

Your confusion might also be coming from having a braced block of code that is not preceded by a keyword.

```
code A

{
    code B
}
```

This is perfectly legal; code blocks do not require control flow keywords, and you can nest your code within braces wherever you like. While it's not terribly common, it's legal. Note that it does create a new variable scope in your code, and (just like all other code blocks) code outside of these blocks will not be able to access any variables declared within the block.

For example:

```
code A

{
    int foo = 10;

    code B
}

int bar = foo; // compiler error, as foo is not a variable within this scope
```

While not advisable, you could use this to declare two identically-named but different variables:

```
{
    int foo = 10;

    code A
}
{
    string foo = "bar";

    code B
}
```

Comment: Huh? In your first example, code B is reachable, no mater what `condition` resolves to. In your second example code B is unreachable if `condition` is staticly false. So in my example the compiler *assumes* an `else`, otherwise there wouldn't be any unreachable code warning to begin with.

Comment: @InBetween: No, it isn't. If `condition` is true, then `code A` will execute and the function will return.

Comment: @AdamRobinson - I will comment about the downvoter, they are silly, for giving you a downvote on the correct conclusion.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter. But the OP is (quite obviously) wondering what a lone `{ block of code; }` means (i.e. with if _or_ else). This answer doesn't recognize that let alone address it

Comment: @sehe: Judging by his comments he was asking both. I've edited my answer to address that as well (I addressed him in the comments to another answer). Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Your confusion comes from the fact that you can include anything in arbitrary `{ }`. For example:

```
{
    Console.WriteLine(a);
    {
        a = 6;
    }
}
{
    Console.WriteLine(a);
}
```

This is perfectly valid and all the curly braces are perfectly pointless. But still valid!

Comment: That would be a nice comment. This is probably all the confusion the OP had

Comment: I'm just writing it in parts. It's longer than that. ;)

Comment: @sehe: It answers the OP's question; why would this be better as a comment?

Comment: @AdamRobinson: mainly because the question was already closed before the answer grew an example :) So yes, I think that any and all answers here would rather have been good comments. The question as such was just incorrect and not constructive.

Comment: @sehe: Also, I just nominated it for reopening. I don't see anything wrong with the question.

Comment: Well, the question is "why is the compiler wrong" when in fact the compiler isn't. The question _could have been_ ok when it asked "Can someone explain how this code makes sense and what it means?" **Edit** And it isn't even a _real programming problem the OP is having_. I don't post any Haskell conundrum just for the fun of having people explain to me that I don't understand Haskell very well :)

Comment: @sehe: Having incorrect assumptions does not make a question not constructive. The OP had these incorrect assumptions, and it's reasonable that others might come here looking to resolve their own.

Comment: @AdamRobinson: fair point. Well taken. However, see my edit to my previous comment as well :)

Comment: This question is silly considering the conclusion the author made is just 100% wrong.  He cannot be helped at this point if he is making the wrong assumptions about bad code.

Comment: @sehe: I'm also not aware of any restriction that says "You must be experiencing the problem in your question". It seems like a reasonable question to me, regardless of its theoretical nature.

Comment: @sehe - this is a rather obscure "feature" of C# syntax, and it could come up in an actual code because of someone mis-editing a file. Therefore, I see the value of this question.

Comment: @Vilx- Ok, I'm with you that the question could have merit. But it _needs_ and edit to be constructive. Also, it is most definitely _not_ an obscure feature (C, C++, Java, Perl and god knows how many other languages _all_ have the same way of nesting (scope) blocks with the same semantics for decades)

Comment: Perhaps a new question, with correct statements/assumptions would be useful. This one is hard to figure out because a couple errors were stated as fact.

Comment: Well, how often have you seen this in any code? :) But, OK, I'll edit it if you deem it necessary for reopening.

Comment: @Vilx-: I happen to be that nerd that limits scope of temporary variables every day even if I don't think it warrants going into a separate method. And, +1 to this answer, now that it is (I think) the only answer that addresses the question. Let's hope it will get reopened :)

Comment: OK, then you're the first person I know that actually does this! Congratulations! :) Btw - interesting notion, the variable scoping aspect had slipped my mind. I might consider doing this myself sometime. Though not often, as it will undoubtedly confuse my colleagues. :D

Answer (score 3):

```
if (true) return;
{
    ... // Unreachable code detected. WTF?
}
```

is equivalent of

```
if (true) 
    return;   
 ... // Unreachable code
```

no else is implied there.

Answer (score 1):

Answer in the comments:

```
if (true) return;
// whatever is after the previous statement will never be executed
// because the previous statement will always return
{
    // this is not automatically added to the "else" part of the previous if
    // this is just a code block with additional braces, which are not 
    // required but valid.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code after the `return` is unreachable. The condition `true` is always, err, `true`.

Comment: well you answer is true, but what does it answer?

Comment: @sehe I probably don't understand the question but I took it to mean that InBetween disputed the fact that the block of code after `return` was unreachable. How should I have interpreted the question?

Comment: reading snippet #1 and #2 closely will show that the OP thought that a 'bare block (`{}`)' is illegal syntax. Hence he asked about '_why does the compiler assume an `else`_'

Comment: @sehe Thanks, but I still don't get. This seems to be one of those questions which requires a little mind-reading. Or perhaps I'm just dumb today. No matter!!

Answer (score 0):

It's a logic issue, not syntax.  Therefore the compiler won't spot it.

As for your third example, it breaks the rules of (most if not all) programming languages and therefore the compiler will spot it and throw an error.

Comment: Er, what rules does the third example break? That's legal C# code.

Comment: But why doesn't the first example break the rules. The bracketed block is effectively the `else` clause of the `if` statement but without the `else` statement.

Comment: @InBetween: It's *effectively* the `else` block. It is not *actually* the `else` block.

Comment: @InBetween: Have you actually tried compiling it? You can create arbitrarily-deep blocks of code with braces. There is no need that they be associated with a control flow keyword like `if`, `else`, `for`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

No. The ';' after your if doesn't close the truepart. It closes all the if. So the block after is reachable code. If your first test failed. The compiler didn't introduce an else. You think that because it's equivalent, but in fact it's not an else.